# Chrome and IE doesn't fire "change" event for autocomplete field in Drupal 7

Tags: google-chrome, drupal-7

I'm building a form with 2 dependant fields - the first is filtering the second. I'm using Drupal 7 Form API and doing it with '#ajax' property to the first field. 
The first field is Drupal autocomplete and may be because of this the "change" event is not triggered. In Firefox it works fine - on Chrome and IE it doesn't.

I tried checking the change event in my js script but it is not triggered at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in the file at /misc/autocomplete.js

change:

```
Drupal.jsAC.prototype.select = function (node) {
  this.input.value = $(node).data('autocompleteValue');
};
```

to:

```
Drupal.jsAC.prototype.select = function (node) {
  this.input.value = $(node).data('autocompleteValue');
  $(this.input).trigger('change');
};
```

this will allow the change trigger to work when the choice in the autocomplete list is clicked.

In order for the change to trigger when it is selected with arrow keys and pressing enter, you need to add the trigger in the hidePopup function changing:

```
Drupal.jsAC.prototype.hidePopup = function (keycode) {
  // Select item if the right key or mousebutton was pressed.
  if (this.selected && ((keycode && keycode != 46 && keycode != 8 && keycode != 27) || !keycode)) {
    this.input.value = $(this.selected).data('autocompleteValue');
  }
  // Hide popup.
  var popup = this.popup;
  if (popup) {
    this.popup = null;
    $(popup).fadeOut('fast', function () { $(popup).remove(); });
  }
  this.selected = false;
  $(this.ariaLive).empty();

};
```

to:

```
Drupal.jsAC.prototype.hidePopup = function (keycode) {
  // Select item if the right key or mousebutton was pressed.
  if (this.selected && ((keycode && keycode != 46 && keycode != 8 && keycode != 27) || !keycode)) {
    this.input.value = $(this.selected).data('autocompleteValue');
    $(this.input).trigger('change');
  }
  // Hide popup.
  var popup = this.popup;
  if (popup) {
    this.popup = null;
    $(popup).fadeOut('fast', function () { $(popup).remove(); });
  }
  this.selected = false;
  $(this.ariaLive).empty();

};
```

Once you make these changes to the autocomplete.js file, you should be able to call the .change trigger like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 Autocomplete uses the event `autocompleteSelect`. This encompasses select and change when done with mouse or keyboard. Depending on how you build or alter a form you will need to set the `#ajax` property in different places. Replace all `my_` prefixed values with your code specific variables.

Building the form yourself in code would be:

```
$form['my_field']['#ajax'] = array(
  'event' => 'autocompleteSelect',
  'callback' => 'my_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'my_wrapper',
);
```

Using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` this is:

```
$form['my_field']['my_language'][0]['target_id']['#ajax'] = array(
  'event' => 'autocompleteSelect',
  'callback' => 'my_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'my_wrapper',
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try use "autocompletechange" event. Some like thet code

```
$('your selector').on('autocompletechange', function() {
    code;
});
```